# ComboBox is Overriding Another ComboBox using Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to use comboboxes to hide/unhide specific sections of my excel sheet.

I have one combobox that hides/unhides a specific block (ComboBox1) of cells and another that hides/unhides sections of cells within that block(ComboBox2).

Everything works accept when I go to unhide the whole block, it overrides the sections that Ive selected hidden within that block.

Is there a way to execute ComboBox2 after clicking ComboBox1 to update the worksheet.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Click()
    ComboBox3.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    ComboBox3.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
    If ComboBox3.Value = "1" Then
        'ranges to be hidden = True/False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox4_Click()
    ComboBox4.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    ComboBox4.List = Array("0", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
    If ComboBox4.Value = "0" Then
        'Ranges to be hidden in ComboBox3 block of cells'
    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to call the Event, just call ComboBox4_Click

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Click()
    ComboBox3.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    ComboBox3.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
    If ComboBox3.Value = "1" Then
     'ranges to be hidden = True/False
    End If

    Combo4Handler

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox4_Click()
    Combo4Handler
End Sub

Private Sub Combo4Handler()
    ComboBox4.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    ComboBox4.List = Array("0", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
    If ComboBox4.Value = "0" Then
    'Ranges to be hidden in ComboBox3 block of cells'
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately in VBA you cannot use "Call" to call an event. Is there another way to do so. Sorry I am very new to VBA

Comment: OK see my edit. just call ComboBox4_Click at the end of ComboBox3_Click. Also do you need to fill the comboboxes everytime theuser clicks on it?

Comment: That solves all of my problems!! Thank you very much! Also yes its a set variable that needs to be fill each time the user clicks on it.

Comment: Explicitly calling event handlers has to be the greatest sin since Hungarian Notation. Extract the code into its own separate procedure, and call that. Don't call event handler procedures manually, that's how you write spaghetti.

Comment: @AndyMorrison you don't need the `Call` keyword to "call" anything whatsoever anyway.